# How to minimize all open windows in c++ with stl

Tags: c++, x11

how i can minimize all open windows in c++?

i need to minimize all open windows in ubuntu (ubuntu 17.10) using a c++ code.
and i don't have any experience about this. i am beginner in c++ and i not know very well libraries. please explain a solution that very very simple and understandable.

i want to create a timer that take a number (in minute) as input, and when this time passed i want to minimize all open windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
int minute = {}, total (0);
   using namespace std::chrono_literals;
   cout << "Enter the minutes: ";
   cin >> minute;
   total = minute * 60;
   for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
   {
      this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
   }
   // in this place i want to minimize all open windows
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Windows are an OS-specific concept. C++ doesn't have concept of GUIs and (hopefully) never will.

Comment: @tambre thanks for your answer, so what i can do? i need to minimize windows. does exist a library for this purpose (excepted xdotool)?

Comment: Depends on the windowing system in use. The solution would be different for X, Wayland, xkcd, gnome, kde, etc... You may be able to find a library to abstract away all the gory details..

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe to a tool that knows the specific window manager interference, for example, `xdotool`:

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Answer (score 0):

`xdotool` doesn't provide this functionality, you need to send `_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP`, see [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html):

Open the display, determine the root window, get the `_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP` atom and then:

> create a ClientMessage event with the specified contents and send it by using a SendEvent request with the following arguments:
>
> ```
> destination     root
> propagate       False
> event-mask      (SubstructureNotify|SubstructureRedirect)
> event           the specified ClientMessage
> ```
>
> Some Window Managers have a "showing the desktop" mode in which windows are hidden, and the desktop background is displayed and focused.
>
> If a Pager wants to enter or leave the mode, it MUST send a `_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP` client message to the root window requesting the change:
>
> ```
>   message_type = _NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP 
>   format = 32
>   data.l[0] = boolean 0 or 1
>   other data.l[] elements = 0
> ```

You also need to either close the display afterwards or run `XFlush()`.